Selenium JavaScript - cannot continue loop of events after opening and closing new tab
I'm building an automated E2E test for an application that lists a bunch of properties. The way I want this flow to work is:

Homepage is a list of properties with links to individual property dashboards.
I open a link in a new tab, open an 'Appliances' box, which will show links to manuals.
I click on each manual link, switch to new tab, and run commands to check that a file exists.
Close the tab with the file, close the tab with the property dashboard, return to the homepage.
Click the next link to the next property on the list.

The loop works the first iteration, but I cannot continue the loop of property URLs for subsequent iterations.
I first simplified my function to isolate why the property-url loop isn't working. I took out the part that checks each appliance and their manual links, and just clicked on a banner in the individual property dashboard that would expand the Appliances button.
If I take out the expandAppliances function from the processLinks function, the loop works fine. But once I open the new tab, interact with the new page, and switch to the home page, I run into the "element not found" error. The error pops up when I try to run
let linkHref = await link.getAttribute("href");
console.log('Link ref: ', linkHref);

I made sure to re-state the links, I made sure to keep switching back and forth between tabs... I have no idea why this loop isn't working. I am getting the length of the links accurately, but the href won't work.
const {By, Builder, Browser, until, Keys} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const assert = require("assert");
require("chromedriver"); 

(async function firstTest() {
    let driver;
    
    try {
        driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
        await driver.get('https://dev.platform.oysterdata.com');
        
        await driver.findElement(By.name('email_address')).sendKeys('###');
        await driver.findElement(By.name('password')).sendKeys('###');
        await driver.findElement(By.css('button[type="submit"]')).click();

        await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('nav-header')), 10000);
        await driver.wait(until.elementsLocated(By.className('property-url')), 10000);
        let links = await driver.findElements(By.className('property-url'));
        
        async function expandAppliances(expandButtons) {
            for (let j = 0; j < expandButtons.length; j++) {
                expandButtons[j].click();
                console.log(`Expand button ${j + 1} clicked`);
                expandButtons[j].click();
            }
        }
        
        async function processLinks() {
            await driver.wait(until.elementsLocated(By.className('property-url')), 10000);
            links = await driver.findElements(By.className('property-url'));
            let windows = await driver.getAllWindowHandles();
            for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                await driver.wait(until.elementsLocated(By.className('property-url')), 10000);
                links = await driver.findElements(By.className('property-url'));
                console.log('Length of links: ', links.length)
                let link = links[i];
                console.log(link);
                let linkHref = await link.getAttribute("href");
                console.log('Link ref: ', linkHref);
                await driver.executeScript("window.open(arguments[0], '_blank');", linkHref);
                console.log(`Opening link ${i + 1}: ${linkHref}`);
                await driver.wait(async () => (await driver.getAllWindowHandles()).length === 2, 10000);
                windows = await driver.getAllWindowHandles();
                await driver.switchTo().window(windows[1]);

                await driver.wait(until.urlContains('property'), 5000);
                await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('Appliances')), 7000).click();
                let expandButtons = await driver.findElements(By.className('expand'));

                await expandAppliances(expandButtons);

                await driver.switchTo().window(windows[0]);
            }
        }

        await processLinks();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}())

